# How do I correctly update setInterval using jquery/javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, setinterval

So I have a div that fades in and out on the screen, and the rate at which this occurs is given by the value of an input which functions as a knob (by using knob.js). I want the user to be able to dynamically change the value on the knob, which will then set the new rate for setInterval. However, this is not happening, it continues to be stuck at the default value regardless of the change on the dial/knob. If anyone can point out what I'm doing wrong, or help in any way I would be very appreciative.

```
  $(function (){
      $(".dial").knob();
      $("#reknob").val().trigger("change");
  });

  function fadeRed() {
      $("#rediv").fadeOut();
      $("#rediv").fadeIn();
  }

  function getRed() {
      refreq=$("#reknob").val();
      return refreq;
  }

 setInterval(function () {
      fadeRed();
      },getRed());
```

Comment: When the value changes (which you can monitor with a `change` or `input` event, then you will need to stop your current interval and then start a new one with the new timing.  The return value from `setInterval()` can be used with `clearInterval()` top stop the timer.

Comment: Also, this is just wrong `$("#reknob").val().trigger("change");`.  Not sure what you were trying to do with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a change handler to reset the interval

```js
$(function() {
  var reknobInterval;
  $("#reknob").knob({
    change: function(v) {
      reset(+v)
    }
  });
  reset(+$("#reknob").val())

  function reset(value) {
    $("#rediv").stop(true, true).show();
    clearInterval(reknobInterval);
    reknobInterval = setInterval(fadeRed, value * 1000); //convert the delay to seconds
  }

  function fadeRed() {
    $("#rediv").fadeOut().fadeIn();
  }
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://anthonyterrien.com/js/jquery.knob.js"></script>

<input id="reknob" class="dial" data-width="150" data-cursor=true data-thickness=.3 data-fgColor="#222222" data-min="1" data-max="10" />
<div id="rediv">rediv</div>
```

Comment: I do have a question though, what does the + in front of the selector do in this line: reset(+$("#reknob").val())?

Comment: @user3394907 `$("#reknob").val()` returns a string, the unary operator `+`, is used to convert the string to a number... shortcut for `parseInt($("#reknob").val(), 10)`